# Is it a good practice to use personal images as profile picture in screen design and mockups?

Tags: best-practice, user-profile

While designing websites and mobile apps is it a good practice to use our own picture as a dummy profile picture.

We might showcase the design to clients or share the design in online communities which might reach a wide range of audience, will this help make ourselves familiar to our audience? or is a bad idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When showing design to clients, have mockups that include realistic titles and images. Clients will otherwise question your design not because it isn't a good design but because the data is not realistic.

When showing design to online communities, use fake *but realistic* titles and images. I can imagine that your clients would not want mockups with real data online.

Whether or not you use actual images of yourselves might be a client-by-client decision, or might just be safer to use stock imagery for the client (to avoid distracting them from the task of design review) and only use images of yourselves when using those designs for promotional purposes.

Comment: Upvoted and added to your answer.